# Errors trying to install aglio with node.js

Tags: windows, node.js, aglio

I am running Node.js 0.10.36 on my windows 7 machine. I also have grunt v0.4.5 and grunt-cli v0.1.13 installed. Python is 2.7.3 and Microsoft Visual studio is 2012.

I am trying to install aglio globally. The command I run is

```
npm install -g aglio
```

The error returned is as follows

[image]

I have been searching the internet for a good resolution to this, but I'm running out of things to try. The main suggestions were to install Python (which I've done) and to set Microsoft Visual Studio to 2012 (which I've also done).

Comment: Well after struggling with this issue for awhile I decided that I might have better luck with a different operating system! So I created a Linux Mint box and everything is working fine!

As for why this never worked on windows I know some of it was related to Microsoft Visual Studio, maybe I needed to install it and it's component software in a different order? I know I needed to install snowcrash first, but I never got it to install correctly on windows.

Comment: I'd like to get an answer on how to make this work in windows, as for me Linux is the way to go!

Comment: I'm curious about this as well because I am having a similar looking issue with a different module